# Spark give Null pointer exception during InputSplit for Hbase

Tags: scala, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, apache-spark

I am using Spark 1.2.1,Hbase 0.98.10 and Hadoop 2.6.0. I got a null point exception while retrieve data form hbase. 
Find stack trace below.

> [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] DEBUG NewHadoopRDD -
>   Failed to use InputSplit#getLocationInfo.
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: null  at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef$.length$extension(ArrayOps.scala:114)
>   ~[scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]    at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.length(ArrayOps.scala:114)
>   ~[scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]    at
>   scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:32)
>   ~[scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]    at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
>   ~[scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$.convertSplitLocationInfo(HadoopRDD.scala:401)
>   ~[spark-core_2.10-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.getPreferredLocations(NewHadoopRDD.scala:215)
>   ~[spark-core_2.10-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$preferredLocations$2.apply(RDD.scala:234)
>   [spark-core_2.10-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$preferredLocations$2.apply(RDD.scala:234)
>   [spark-core_2.10-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]     at
>   scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120) [scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.preferredLocations(RDD.scala:233)
>   [spark-core_2.10-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal(DAGScheduler.scala:1326)
>   [spark-core_2.10-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply$mcVI$sp(DAGScheduler.scala:1336)
>   [spark-core_2.10-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1335)
>   [spark-core_2.10-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1335)
>   [spark-core_2.10-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]     at
>   scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
>   [scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal$2.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1335)
>   [spark-core_2.10-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal$2.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1333)
>   [spark-core_2.10-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]     at
>   scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
>   [scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal(DAGScheduler.scala:1333)
>   [spark-core_2.10-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply$mcVI$sp(DAGScheduler.scala:1336)
>   [spark-core_2.10-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1335)
>   [spark-core_2.10-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1335)
>   [spark-core_2.10-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]     at
>   scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
>   [scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal$2.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1335)
>   [spark-core_2.10-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal$2.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1333)
>   [spark-core_2.10-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]     at
>   scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
>   [scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal(DAGScheduler.scala:1333)
>   [spark-core_2.10-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.getPreferredLocs(DAGScheduler.scala:1304)
>   [spark-core_2.10-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$17.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:862)
>   [spark-core_2.10-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$17.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:859)
>   [spark-core_2.10-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>   [scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>   [scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]     at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
>   [scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]     at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
>   [scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]     at
>   scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
>   [scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]     at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
>   [scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>   [scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]     at
>   scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
>   [scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitMissingTasks(DAGScheduler.scala:859)
>   [spark-core_2.10-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:778)
>   [spark-core_2.10-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleJobSubmitted(DAGScheduler.scala:762)
>   [spark-core_2.10-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(DAGScheduler.scala:1389)
>   [spark-core_2.10-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]     at
>   akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)
>   [akka-actor_2.10-2.3.4-spark.jar:na]  at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor.aroundReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1375)
>   [spark-core_2.10-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]     at
>   akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
>   [akka-actor_2.10-2.3.4-spark.jar:na]  at
>   akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
>   [akka-actor_2.10-2.3.4-spark.jar:na]  at
>   akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
>   [akka-actor_2.10-2.3.4-spark.jar:na]  at
>   akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
>   [akka-actor_2.10-2.3.4-spark.jar:na]  at
>   akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
>   [akka-actor_2.10-2.3.4-spark.jar:na]  at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>   [scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>   [scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>   [scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
>   [scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]

Please provide me solution for this problem.

Comment: Can you paste the code that throws this exception?

Comment: sparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(hbaseConf,
                TableInputFormat.class, ImmutableBytesWritable.class, Result.class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Exception  is thrown in the getPreferredLocations phase so without more information about your hbase ConfigurationI suggest you look at  the hbase.table.name and the hbase.master (this last one i do not if the correct to define the HMaster) are configured as you want

Comment: I am able to read/write data on hbase using spark and without spark.

Comment: No issue when using hbase 0.98.6, hadoop 2.5.0 and spark 1.1.0